# Why does React Router break unless I use Link components?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, jekyll, url-routing

I am migrating a project from a very old version of `react-router` to the newer `react-router-dom`. I have the following code in my top level react component:

```
import React from "react";
import {createRoot} from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import NewPage from "./components/NewPage";

const TestComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to={"/new_page"}>GO TO ROUTE</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<TestComponent />} />
      <Route path="/new_page" element={<NewPage />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

This code works fine. When I click on the link, the `NewPage` component is rendered.

The problem is that if I manually type in `http://localhost:3001/new_page`, I get this error: `Cannot GET /new_page`. It doesn't make sense to me that the Link is able to navigate there but I am not able to manually.

The project is built with jekyll, webpack, and react. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is an issue with how the React app is being hosted and served. The gist is that all page requests should return the app's root index.html file so the React app can load and redirect internally to the appropriate route. How are you running the app? Are you deploying the app to a host service?

Comment: @DrewReese To be honest I'm not even sure how to answer that question (I am new to this project and am not used to jekyll). Currently not hosting anywhere, just trying to run locally. There is a file called `default.html` in the jekyll `_layouts` folder. I am putting a div in that html body with an `id="root` which I use to render the react. Then I use gulp to build all the html and compile js code? My guess is that jekyll is the one to blame but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around exactly how all the parts fit together.

Comment: Something is starting a webserver locally on port 3001 , that something needs to be configured (somehow) to serve `default.html` for all requests that don't match an existing file.

Comment: @apokryfos @DrewReese The `gulpfile.js` is responsible for running on port 3001 using `browserSync`. I am unable to add code because there are too many pending edits on stackoverflow at the moment